# Requested operation is invalid on closed state using ArcSDE for Oracle?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, cursor

I have a version on an Oracle SDE that I am working on using ArcMap / ArcPy 10.2.1.

I started an edit session and inserted a row in to a feature. Saved the edit and stopped editing.

[image]

I then tried inserting data through an arcpy script.

```
val = [uuid.uuid4(),'bryan', dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),
       dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
       'ins','qa','0','','done','xyz','test','','206901','5997594',
       'id1','id2','terr','co1','flag','issue','bid','official',
       'area','kv','sub','0','99',uuid.uuid4(), arcpy.Point(206901, 5997594)]
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(myconnect)
edit.startEditing(False, True)    
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor("V.DATA/V.TABLE",fieldnames) as iCur:
    iCur.insertRow(val)
edit.stopOperation()            
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

When the section of code executes below it fails at the iCur.insertRow(val) line.

```
RuntimeError('The requested operation is invalid on a closed state [V.TABLE]',), <traceback object at 0x0DB535D0>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Dang it! In my over-eagerness in cleaning up my code, I removed the **edit.startOperation()** call before making my edit changes. Of course I just assumed it was there until someone else was looking over the code with me!